# Magento2 How to create accordion checkout flow

Tags: magento2, checkout, onestepcheckout

I want to create checkout flow like Magento 1 in Magento 2.
Can any one guide me for that how can I achieve this in Magento 2.

[image]

Comment: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/javascript-dev-guide/widgets/widget_accordion.html try this